# How do I pass values between templates in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel Framework 4.1.30.

How do you pass a data from one template to another without passing through route or controller?

Specifics: I got a "Main" blade template that is extended by a "Sign-in" blade template. My objective is to put any errors that appears in the the "Sign-in" template and displayed this to a footer section of the "Main" template.

My codes for main template inside the "body" tag are as follows (note some codes exist in between to format my view):

```
<!-- Serving as Header -->
@include('layout.navigation')

<!-- Serving as left content/status displays -->
@include('layout.frameleft') 

<!-- Serving as right content/entry point -->
@yield('content')

<!-- Serving as Error Notification/footer -->
@if (Session::has('global'))
      {{ Session::get('global') }}
@endif
```

The blade template calling the Main is coded like so:

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')

    ... more code here / input fields ...

    {{ $errors->first('email')}}

    ... more code here / input fields ...

@stop
```

As I understand it (fairly new to Laravel) the content gets to be read first before the session display global.

I was hoping, a simple variable passing between template would be enough (if it exist) to resolve the problem. I wish to pass the error value from the content back to the main template on the footer section part without going back to controller.

I am aware there are work-arounds, like instead of waiting for controller to output the errors to template, I could pass the errors directly to global variable via session (or to layout) from Controller. Currently the following working code is what I have implemented  but I'm just wondering what if the data was passed already to the template.

```
public function postSignin() {

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
            array(
                    'email'     => 'required|email',
                    'password'  => 'required'
            )
        ); 

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            $errors = $validator->errors();
            $formErrors = 'Errors: ';

            foreach($errors->all() as $error ) {
                $formErrors .= sprintf("%s", $error);
            }

            return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput()
                ->with('global',$formErrors);

        } else {

        ...more codes here...
```

Why I'm doing so is that originally my code at the controller is just like..

```
        if ($validator->fails()) {

           return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
              ->withErrors($validator)
              ->withInput();
```

Now it seem so big. I figure if I can relieve the controller with a loop, my program would be more efficient.

Comment: Alvin, can you in any way split up your questions? Please ask **one** question at a time.

Comment: Noted, It's just that Q2 and Q3 may be the answer to Q1 and Q4 can be another option to answer Q1.

Comment: @AlvinCaseria Regarding Q2 : You might want to look at View::share(), which is something like this `View::share('name', 'Steve');` check the (docs)[http://laravel.com/docs/responses]

Comment: Yes that's what I use when I'm in the controller. But the question was while I'm at the template.

Comment: @AlvinCaseria Please don't say "latest" because this question will still be here in five years and then it won't be true anymore. State the version.

Comment: Also, you noted a different question and that you want "other solutions". How so? How is your question different to the other? (as a sidenote, your question is discussed on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-ask-many-things?cb=1 )

Comment: Thanks I'll post the version as soon as I'm on my computer. For the Q2 and Q3 as I explained, they are the possible answer for Q1. As for Q4... I stated Q1 does not use routes nor Controller but Q4 is ommiting this statement. Both of which (Q1 and Q4) however have same scenario and question/problem.

Comment: @AlvinCaseria So ask one question, then use the information you get from answers to determine if it is also the solution to your other potential question. If not, ask a new question. Doing it like this simply confuses the issue and makes it harder to give a complete and correct answer.

Comment: It doesn't really matter for the question itself, but there's no such MySQL *server* version as 14.14 - that's the version of the MySQL *client* command line tool.  To get the server version, run `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: What I have when I run mysql --version is Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2... are you implying I lied?

Comment: No, you didn't lie, you are just looking in the wrong place. `mysql --version` tells you what the *command line client application*'s version is, which is entirely irrelevant since your question is not about the command line client.  If you run the command line client and execute `SELECT VERSION();` it will tell you the *server*'s version number.

Comment: Yup sorry will edit that later to 5.5.37

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#error-messages-and-views) (emphasis theirs):

> However, notice that we do not have to explicitly bind the error messages to the view in our GET route. This is because Laravel will always check for errors in the session data, and automatically bind them to the view if they are available. **So, it is important to note that an `$errors` variable will always be available in all of your views, on every request**, allowing you to conveniently assume the $errors variable is always defined and can be safely used. The `$errors` variable will be an instance of `MessageBag`.

Because Laravel's `Redirect... withErrors()` method does this, you don't need to add the errors to the Session again by hand.  Instead of checking for `if (Session::has('global'))`, just do this:

```
<!-- Serving as Error Notification/footer -->
@foreach ($errors as $error)
    <p>{{ $error }}</p>
@endforeach
```

This should work *even though* it is in the `layout` and not in the actual view, because binding that applies `errors` inside the template also applies them outside of it.

If there are no errors, Laravel will just skip that block.  If there are errors, they will have been automatically bound to the `$errors` variable and will be rendered as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I was originally writing up an answer that recommended [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers), but then I re-read the question and I believe what you need to do is abstract out the form validation to a 'form' class:

```
interface FormInterface {
    public function isValid($input);
    public function errors();
}
```

The basic idea I got from your question is that you want your controller to look something like this:

```
public function postSignIn()
{
    if(!$this->_signinForm->isValid(Input::all())) {
        return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
            ->withErrors($this->_signinForm->errors())
            ->withInput()
        ;
    }

    // Non-error logic branch
}
```

Your form class will basically contain a reference to the validator object.  All the `isValid` method should do is basically call `passes()` on the validator, and all the `error` method will simply return the results of calling `errors()` on the validator.

I honestly have no idea why you're actually combining all of the error messages into a single variable, I assume its because you want them all displayed in the same place.  If that's the case and that's how you want the errors to function, then you can build that in to your form's `errors` method.

Comment: Althought it does not answer the question. It does help my current a lot. Appreciate it.